# Capturing fdisk output into an array and printing it

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I want to get a list of partitions on the system...

I use this command

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep '^/dev' | awk '{print $1}'
```

The output is

```
/dev/sda1

/dev/sda2
```

I need to get this result as first result in array index 0 and next as array index 1, and I need to be able to print it whereever I want.

I want to get more values likewise for my network group... I need this array output in for looping so that it automatically fetches the values like each device name and its partition.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your shell is bash, use the [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-2mapfile) command with input from a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

```
mapfile -t disks < <(sudo fdisk -l | awk '/^\/dev/ {print $1}')
```

I removed the unnecessary grep from the pipeline since awk can do that.

You can inspect the contents of the array with `declare -p disks`

Comment: Hy hi @glenn jackman thats not the issue i have received the output but here what i need is to get the output in an array and i need to give the stored array index to another variable it is what i need

Comment: I'm not clear about what you need "to give the stored array index to another variable" -- please show (in your question) exactly what the contents of the array should be.

Comment: ok glenn let me show it...I do have two - three disks in my clients so i need to store the output of sudo fdisk -l | grep '^/dev' | awk '{print $1}' which will shows the device names of the system so i want to load it an variable with an array and i need to use it variables.

Comment: you're just repeating what you've already written: show, in your question, what the contents of the array are supposed to be. Do you need the number of sectors, partition size, etc?

Comment: yes glenn i need to partition size , device name and name of the sector that's it